Manga in which the main character dies in a bus accident
The MC once lived in an ordinary world trying not to stand out he entered a bus to get to somewhere, when a strong looking and well-built man, in an effort that others don't get harmed, he chooses to give his seat to the man and after a while everything was well until the bus had an accident in which the MC was flung towards the front windshield of the bus and was slowly dying, as he looks back into the bus everyone was fine but he sees that the same man was smiling and recording his death

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Does something happen after he dies?  Is he reincarnated, regressed, or isekaied?  What science fiction or fantasy elements are there in this story?

This question doesn't appear to be about Science Fiction or Fantasy

Why was the MC "trying not to stand out"? Was there something supernatural about him?

This is The Girl, the Shovel, and the Evil Eye

Tsuguto Sumihara is way too nice... or rather, was too nice. He lost
his life in a bus accident after being bullied into giving up his
seat, and somehow was reincarnated into a mining camp! Not only that,
the mine is at the base of an impossibly tall tower. It's there he
meets the ram -- horned Loulier, his first friend in this bizarre
land. But when she's bullied, Tsuguto finds that maybe he wasn't
reincarnated without powers after all... and that, if he's to have a
future in this strange new land, Loulier's just the partner he needs.


If this is the correct answer (and I'm pretty sure it is) then question is on topic. Guy gets isekaied to magic world.
